# If the sum over a tensor is zero, does the tensor also equal zero?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Given the following expression:
$$g^{ab}A_{ab}=0$$
Where the sum over the indices of the tensor $A_{ab}$, with the metric tensor, equals zero. Is it true to say that the tensor $A_{ab}$ also equals zero?

If so, does the same hold in the more general case, where the sum over the indices of one contravariant tensor $B^{ab}$ multiplied by a covariant tensor $A_{ab}$ equals zero?
$$B^{ab}A_{ab}=0$$

Will this be true for tensors with any amount of indices, and of any type, or only for specific tensors?

Comment: No, and for very trivial dimension reasons. This is just a trace condition, so there could very well be other non-zero components (unless you're in 1-dimension... then there's only 1 component and that will be 0 (assuming you use the metric tensor, but for arbitrary $B^{ab}$, not necessarily)).

Comment: In a specific case of a metric tensor (which is usually symmetric, though, in a curved space, can also contain non-diagonal components), $ g^{ab}A_{ab}=0\,$ for any anty-symmetric tensor $A_{ab}$ (what, of course, does not imply that $A_{ab}$ is degenerate, or even more so, zero)

Comment: $$A_{jk}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-\frac{1}{r^2}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$g^{jk}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&r^2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$g^{jk}A_{jk}=0$$